# Finding a word in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following simple code works if one needs to find a whole word in a sentence string. Can anyone critique it, or find boundary conditions where this may fail?

```
a = input("Enter a sentence:")
w = input ("Enter a word to be found in the sentence")
if w.lower() in a.lower():
   print("It is present")
else:
   print("It is not present")
```

Comment: It depends more on the interpretation of the question. Is the word "car" found in the sentence "I like your scarf"? Some people will say yes — there is "car" inside "scarf" — and for those people, your code works correctly. Some people will say no — "car" is not a word in that sentence — and they would judge your code as incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per @Amadan's comment,

> It depends more on the interpretation of the question. Is the word "car" found in the sentence "I like your scarf"? Some people will say yes — there is "car" inside "scarf" — and for those people, your code works correctly.

For this, your code works perfectly fine.

```
a = input("Enter a sentence:")
w = input ("Enter a word to be found in the sentence:")
if w.lower() in a.lower():
   print("It is present")
else:
   print("It is not present")
```

Output:

```
Enter a sentence:I like your scarf
Enter a word to be found in the sentence:car
It is present
>>>
```

> Some people will say no — "car" is not a word in that sentence — and they would judge your code as incorrect.

For this, use:

```
a = input("Enter a sentence:")
w = input ("Enter a word to be found in the sentence:")
if w.lower() in a.lower().split():
   print("It is present")
else:
   print("It is not present")
```

output:

```
Enter a sentence:I like your scarf
Enter a word to be found in the sentence:car
It is not present
```

Answer (score 0):

This works perfectly. Since the `input()` treats everything as string, you can even check for special characters or words which have accented letters.

Comment: Hello @Deepesh Joy, I feel that the code snippet will not be optimal as we should as a good practice, store string in a list in comparisions :)